# Getting excel activex calendar control working on all machines

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which contains a calendar control (Microsoft Calendar Control 2007, MSCAL.ocx) and activex comboBox controls.

All works fine on my own PC but when i try it on another one (with the same version of excel i.e. 2007) it seems to lose the reference to the Microsoft Calendar Control 2007. I get an error message saying "Invalid qualifier" every time I reference the calendar in the VBA code.

I am hoping to find a solution to this problem that doesn't require the user to go into the VB editor and add a reference as this spreadsheet will be sent to many users, can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to get the user to register the calendar control using a batch file, not ideal but it works